# With http 302 response, when redirect, the part start with '#' in url was stripped by browser

Tags: http, browser, anchor, http-status-code-302

After sending request to an API, I get a `302` response:

With headers:

- `Status` = `302`
- `Location`  = `http://some.com/#token=xyz`

Then the browser *(chrome)* send another request automatically, to `http://some.com/`, with the `#token=xyz` part striped, thus the token was missing.

Tested this with `curl`, it won't strip the `#...` part as browser does.

Maybe, replacing `#` with `?` is a solution. But the API is from 3rd-party, not within my control.

---

### Questions

- Why does the browser drop it, while `curl` won't?
  Is it thinking `#` *(anchor)* part is useless in the 302 case?
- Is there any way to make browser keep the `#...` part, during a `302` redirection.
- Any other way to get the `#...` part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the fragment part is never sent in a request; it's processed locally by the user agent. See https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#rfc.section.5.1.p.2.

Comment: Ok, so it's called `fragment`.